# Export SSRS local report to pdf Without Rendering it in report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I want to write c# code to make  **Export SSRS local report  to pdf** ***Without Rendering it in report viewer***

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LocalReport.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to obtain a Byte array that you can save using FileStream.

Comment: i don't want to render the report in front of the user as it takes long time on large  amount of data..

Comment: LocalReport.Render don't use ReportViewer and don't preview anything to final user. It simply render your report in the format specified.

Answer (score -2):

You could do it without any C# by using the Subscriptions feature on the Report server, this has options to output in PDF to a file location, or send via email.